# Need help with signal modulation

Tags: rf, vna, frequency-modulation

To capture a mammalian cell, I need to have a constant 4MHz AC signal (coming from a function generator) while sweeping the frequency from the vector network analyzer (VNA) 9kHz to 9GHz to read the scattering parameters.

Mammalian cells usually can be captured at low frequencies between 1 to 10 MHz by coplanar waveguide electrodes (CPW.) This is why I want to apply a constant 4 MHz signal to capture the cell. By sweeping a radio frequency from low to high I can read its electrical properties. I am looking for a way to apply these two signals together to capture and sweep the frequency simultaneously.

What is the best way of doing this?

Suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: what cell are you talking about?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience.

I am looking for a way to have a constant 4Mhz AC signal (coming from a function generator) while sweeping the frequency (from the vector network analyzer (VNA) 9kHz to 9GHz) to read the scattering parameters. 
I am wondering what is the best way of doing this.

Comment: @Ferrofluid - that just repeats the question without any additional information. What do you want to get the scattering parameters of? Where does the 4MHz need to be injected? Draw a diagram. Put all the information in the question - not in the comments.

Comment: So mammalian Cells usually can be captured at low frequencies between 1 to 10 Mhz by coplanar waveguide electrodes (CPW). this is why I want to apply a constant 4 MHz signal to capture the cell.

By sweeping an rf frequency from low to high I can read its electrical properties. I am looking for a way to apply these two signals together to capture and sweep the frequency simultaneously.

Comment: Seems like a highly specialized topic for a general Electrical Engineering site. Instead, search using keywords "ultra-wideband 2-port impedance spectroscopy" and you'll find papers like this: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/ielaam/7397573/9004974/8731641-aam.pdf. The signals are not combined, they are applied to 2 separate ports.

Comment: What do you mean by "to capture the cell" --> are you saying that animal cells somehow migrate towards your 4 MHz (not 4Mhz) source? Then, it seems you want to read its electrical properties once you have captured it? What properties are you talking about? Do you expect EEs will naturally understand what it is that you want to do? TBH I'm totally confused by this question.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt Yes, we are doing the same, and in fact this a research paper that we are replicating but instead of the dielectrophoresis method for capturing the cell we looking for an analog device to help us to apply both frequencies at the same time. we kind of want to interface the waves.
i had a search on the internet and found RF mixers nad directional couplers but I am not sure if they are suitable for our job or not!

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, in low frequencies, cells can be captured by electrodes like coplanar or vertical waveguide electrodes. And yes by sweeping the frequency from low to high we can read the electrical properties of the cell. Yes there are software simulations such as advance design system (ADS) or Ansys HFSS that with the help of them we can validate our results.

Comment: @Andyaka
Till now cells have been captured by electrophoresis and microfluidic channels between the electrodes to read their electrical properties.
I am wondering if there is an analog device that can help us to apply both of frequencies simultaneously. (4MHz and sweeping frequency 30kHz to 9GHz)?
. I had a search on the internet and found RF mixers nad directional couplers but I am not sure if they are suitable for our job or not!

Comment: @KevinWhite
Sorry for the confusion, I edited my question and explained it more. I would appreciate it if you share any idea or solution with me.

Comment: @jsotola Sorry for the confusion, I edited my question and explained it more. I would appreciate it if you share any ideas or solutions with me.

Comment: You need to define the interface between the cells and the electrodes. Nobody on EE will have any idea about this. This is why you have received no help. Folk will if they can but they have no mental picture of what you want or why you are doing it.